# Google sign in not redirect to application after allow

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus, google-authentication

I'm using this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/) to implement Sign in with google in app.

1. I installed GoogleSignIn via cocoapods. `pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 2.4.0'`
2. Added `GSignIn-Bridging-Header.h` with `#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>` inside.
3. Create url types: [image]
4. Create a view with `GIDSignInButton` class
5. Added code:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate,    GIDSignInUIDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "KEY" 
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
   if let err = error {
      print(error)
   }
   else {
      print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.name)
      print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.email)
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idSegueContent", sender: self)
     }
   }


   func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

   }
   }
   ```
6. But when i click allow

[image]

It redirects me to google.com, not to app.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift
use this

Comment: hi you have got any error?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: <GMR/DEBUG> Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, _e, {
     "_et" = 16107;
     "_o" = auto;
 }
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: this is last debug message from console

Comment: @Arti any result ?

Comment: @Bonnke sorry, i forgot to post answer and don't remember now how i fixed it :( But i remember i missed something in configs...

Comment: @Arti Man, Please try to find the answer, and post it. This is very critical to me at this moment, and no idea what happened. I did not touch any configs. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but just try to close viewcontroller in didSignInForUser method: self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Bonnke this is my code: http://pastebin.com/cYtWUXuW   Say if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AppDelegate, You need to add the Implementation of

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Google sends back information through URL, the method above captures this information and send back to the Application.

Comment: can you please tell me how FBSDKApplicationDelegate is redirecting for Google Sign in, Is it bug when we implement with Facebook login. As user has also accepted your answer.

Comment: FBSDK redirect back to your application when login is done, The sourceApplication delegate method should be called then, and you should check then the url.scheme and return true or false.

Comment: didnt understand how it can work? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @Sam You may need to open an URL using : UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
What if from that web page you needed to go back to your App?
You can create a hyper link in that web page and in that action Put the URL scheme of URL App.
What happens then that the App with that URL scheme get called thought the App Delegate method "sourceApplication"
In that method you can check about the URL scheme that called back your App and determine weather or not you want to open back your App.
That's what Facebook SDK do in order to return back to your App after you login successfully.

Comment: @AymanIbrahim I am using gpluse login how should I allow only my company gmail id like xxxx@xxx.club to sigin from my app.

Answer (score 5):

I finally fixed this after a day's work. @ayman Ibrahim was basically, right, but I think that the answer is a bit broader. Different versions of Swift/Objective-C and the Google SDK, call different versions of the canOpenURL method in the AppDelegate. I'm not 100% certain about that, and would appreciate confirmation or correction. Here is the version of that method which worked for me. I am using Google's SDK v. 4.0, targeting iOS 9.1, and using Swift 3.0:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let checkFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let checkGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
    return checkGoogle || checkFB
}
```

I am also using the FBSDK, so ignore that line.

Comment: Also, for debugging purposes, define as many versions of that method as you can, and use breakpoints or prints, to figure out which one is being called.

Answer (score 0):

I did found another answer for it. In my case, in AppDelegate I did implement 2 delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

The first is the delegate method and should not implement anymore, it was replaced by the the second method. But somehow I still use both and just add

```
return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                          annotation:annotation];
```

in the second one and then somehow again, it just callback to the first method then it not navigate to my app anymore.

So I want to post my case for someone who may get this mistake to, it took me too long to find out

Answer (score 0):

If you have integrated CleverTap library `CleverTap.autoIntegrate()` in your app delegate will not redirect the user back to the application. Adding CleverTap events manually will resolve this issue. If you have done everything else right.